# The Milos Framework from EPS

Tags: frameworks

I'm currently investigating the [Milos Framework](http://www.milossolutionplatform.com/) from EPS Consulting but I have not been able to find much in the way of useful information available on the subject. There is some broad brush stuff on the web site such as this [high level architecture](http://www.milossolutionplatform.com/Features.aspx) diagram and there is a help file containing the API definition but nothing in the middle.

It is written by the same guys that write for [CODE magazine](http://www.code-magazine.com/Index.aspx) ([Markus Egger](http://www.markusegger.com/) and [Claudio Lassala](http://claudiolassala.spaces.live.com/blog/)) so I'd expect it to be good as they are both excellent writers but to get access to the code or get a price you have to "call our sales team for a consult". (grrr...)

Does anyone have any experience with or knowledge of this framework?

What I have found so far is that it covers:

- User Interface Components
- Data and Middle Tier Components
- Application Fundamentals (Business Objects?)
- Tools and Processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the Milos website:** "Milos is a software development platform — a set of components, processes and tools for crafting scalable and extensible enterprise applications using Microsoft .NET technology. We do not call Milos a “framework” - although it includes a complete and powerful tier of framework technical components. It presents both lower- (technical infrastructure) and higher-level (business logic) components; and it includes processes and tools."

Milos encompasses 4 areas:

### Data and Middle Tier Components

```
* Business Entities
* Service Enabled Business Objects
* Data Access Layer
```

### User Interface Components

```
* Windows
* Web
* Touchscreen
* WPF
```

Includes some  grid controls but these are for WinForms only.
Includes some  charting controls but these are for WinForms only.

### Business Building Blocks

```
* Credit Card Processing
* Names Management
* Security
* Shopping Cart
* Error Handling & Logging
* Document Management
* EMail
* Invoices / Receipts / Payments / POS
* Blog & RSS
* Application Configuration
* Output Queue
```

### Developer Tools

```
* Developer Services Code Generation Tools
* Developer Services Data Object Test Harness
* Test Driven Development Tools
```

There is support for .Net 2003 and 2005 but no mention of 2008.

I also found [this](http://perseus.franklins.net/dotnetrocks_0147_houston.pdf) reference to the framework on Dot Net Rocks.

From what I can piece together from Markus' blog, the framework is still largely focused on the WinForms and ASP.Net platforms although they have recently introduced components for WPF and Silverlight development. (See  [this](http://www.milossolutionplatform.com/MilosBlog.aspx) blog posting for some info on one of their Silverlight controls and [this](http://www.milossolutionplatform.com/MilosBlog.aspx?blogid=b1a9b570-faca-496f-91b1-381564400cd3&startdate=6/1/2008%2012:00:00%20AM&enddate=6/30/2008%2012:00:00%20AM) blog posting for a reference to a "Simple WPF Control Suite").